SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='<example>', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /<suffix> in AWS Glue Job

SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='', port=443): Max retries
exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL:
TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version
(_ssl.c:1129)'))) in AWS Glue Job

I am encountering an SSL error while trying to connect to an API endpoint using Python 3.9 in an AWS Glue job. The error message I receive is:
raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='<host>', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /<suffix> (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:1129)')))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):

class GlueJob:
    def __init__(self, geo_url, eoae_geo_key):
        self.geo_url = geo_url
        self.eoae_geo_key = eoae_geo_key


    def get_geo_data(self, activity_id: str):
        payload = json.dumps({
            "key": self.eoae_geo_key,
            "activity": activity_id
        })
        headers = {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }

        response = requests.post(self.geo_url, headers=headers, data=payload, verify=False)
        return response.json()

Here are the details of my setup and the relevant parts of my code:
AWS Glue Shell
Python Version: 3.9

My setup in job parameters:
--python-modules-installer-option: "psycopg2-binary,geopandas,apache-sedona,geoalchemy2,sqlalchemy,tqdm,ipython,urllib3==1.26.16,requests==2.26.0"

--python-modules-installer-option: "--upgrade"

Question:
How can I resolve the tlsv1 alert protocol version error in my AWS Glue job? Are there specific configurations or packages that I need to update or install to ensure compatibility with the API's TLS version?

Some of the libs that you added already exists by default in glue: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-python-libraries.html#glue-modules-provided

Yep I try to using default lib but it's not working
